# AndroidStudio won't compile for me

Tags: java, android, android-studio, classpath, java-6

I'm running Android Studio on Mac OSX Sierra.

I'm helping my CTO get our android up and running for a client (our Android dev had a family emergency).

I'm receiving the following error when I attempt a build:

> Error:Cannot run program "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/tutash/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta/compile-server"): error=2, No such file or directory

I'm fairly certain this is a classpath issue, and I've installed JDK 1.6.0 via Apple. Any quick fix out there to help me get this at least to the next error?